# Как в chrome посмотреть шрифт?

Tags: шрифты

Подскажите, как в chrome, в инспекторе кода посмотреть шрифт на сайте, т.е. не название шрифта, используемого на сайте, а его начертание, т.е. как выглядят все буквы.
Есть такая возможность во встроенных методах браузера?

Comment: дак вставьте алфавит в текстовый блок с этим шрифтом да и все дела? Тем более, если у вас шрифт показывается, то он либо есть в системе, либо подключается. В первом случае, просмотреть его можете либо в папке шрифтов, либо выбрав в любом другом браузере, а если нет, то всегда можете его скачать с этого же сайта

Comment: @teran, вроде есть встроенная возможность

Comment: где эта папка шрифтов?

Comment: `C:\Windows\Fonts`, но если шрифт установлен, то вы его и в том же ворде и т.п. можете выбрать.

Comment: @teran, вроде можно в инспекторе кода как-то посмотреть папку шрифтов

Comment: как прописан это шрифт?

Comment: @teran, не совсем понятно, что прописано?